# At an event , If there are m actors, n singers and r tables , find the number of ways you can place the guests. (tables are alike)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, stirling-numbers

So the question asks us to find the total arrangements possible given the no. of singers, actors and tables given the fact that -

- **A table can have either only singers or only actors, not both.**
- **No table can have only one actor**
- **None of the tables are left empty**

> Here's what I tried -

Select m tables for the actors (mCr) , and the remaining r-m tables for n singers (m-nCr).

The no. of ways to distribute distinct objects into alike boxes is S(n,r). (Stirling no. of second kind)

Therefore - S(m,m) x S(m-r,n) is what I am left with.

How do I make sure none of the actors are seated alone?

Comment: Please use latex in your post by enclosing the math symbols in $ \$ $. Also it is Stirling, not Sterling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint$_1$:** You want to use the *Associated Stirling numbers of the second kind*.  
**Hint$_2$:**
For this particular case, you can try using inclusion-exclusion. Let the sets $A_i = \{ \text{distribution of $m$ actors in $k$ tables such that the $i$-th actor is alone}\}$. Show that $|A_i|=S(m-1,k-1)$. What is then $\left |\bigcap _{i\in I}A_i\right |$?
Compute $S(m,k)-\left |\bigcup _{i=1}^m A_i\right |$.

Comment: What is the recursion equation for the associated stirling numbers of the second kind such that there are at least 2 objects in a box?

Comment: @kendrick023 Like the one in Stirling numbers, but instead of leaving the last one (i.e., $n+1$) in a singleton, you find an element out of $n$ options to put it with it. So you get $n\cdot S(n-1,k-1)+k\cdot S(n-1,k)$

Comment: @kendrick023 Yes. Sorry, there is a typo on my comment. It should be: $nS(n-1,k-1)+kS(n,k)$. There I am, of course, considering $S(n+1,k)$.

Comment: So just to reiterate : 
S(n,k) = nS(n−1,k−1)+kS(n,k)
Correct?

Comment: @kendrick023 No, the left hand side should be $S(n+1,k)$. You can accommodate the RHS if you want $S(n,k)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131061/discussion-between-kendrick023-and-phicar).